# MySite profile category names

Tags: my-profile

For SharePoint 2010, is it possible to edit/change MySite profile category names.  As an example, I would like to change "Ask Me About:" to "Skills & Talents:".

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Manage User Properties" option under your the User profile application's setting page in Central Administration. Locate the "Ask Me About" and select "edit". You can change the display name in the edit page.